# Migrate Controllers to Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.0.4 and want to migrate to Spring 4 (4.1.3 is the current latest version). I am currently using `SimpleFormController` based classes, so I have to migrate to using `@Controller`. I have already used this in a Spring Boot based application, but this one is quite old.

For example, in my `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>exportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/exportServlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>exportServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/export/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In `exportServlet-config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- ========================= MVC CONFIG ========================= -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="com.traficon.tmsng.server.web.mvc.ExportEventViewResolver">
        <!-- where to find the XML data in the model map -->
        <property name="sourceKey" value="src"/>
        <!-- where XSLT files are stored -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/xsl/"/>
        <!-- suffix of xsl file -->
        <property name="suffix" value=".xsl"/>
        <!-- all view names match -->
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
        <property name="cacheTemplates" value="false"/>
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="com.traficon.tmsng.server.web.mvc.DefaultExportEventView"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                /eventhistory*.html=exportEventController
                /eventhistory*.zip=exportEventController
                /eventhistory*.xls=exportEventController
                /integrateddatahistory*.html=exportIntegratedDataController
                /integrateddatahistory*.xls=exportIntegratedDataController
                /flowdatahistory*.html=exportFlowDataController
                /flowdatahistory*.xls=exportFlowDataController
                /presencedatahistory*.html=exportPresenceDataController
                /presencedatahistory*.xls=exportPresenceDataController
                /bicycledatahistory*.html=exportBicycleDataController
                /bicycledatahistory*.xls=exportBicycleDataController
                /logging*.html=exportLoggingController
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- ========================= CONTROLLERS ========================= -->

    <bean id="exportEventController" class="com.traficon.tmsng.server.web.mvc.ExportEventController">
        <property name="commandClass"
                  value="com.traficon.tmsng.server.web.mvc.ExportEventControllerCommandBean"/>
        <property name="supportedMethods" value="POST,GET"/>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="86400"/>
    </bean>


    <bean class="com.traficon.tmsng.server.web.export.MessageExporterRunnable" scope="prototype"/>
</beans>
```

To update, I remove the stuff from web.xml and update the `ExportEventController` class. My updated class now uses the `@Controller` annotation (`ExportMessageController` is an abstract class which *no longer* extends from SimpleFormController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/export")
public class ExportEventController extends ExportMessageController<EventMessage, ExportEventControllerCommandBean>
{
    // Need to allow GET because Air client converts POST into a GET
    @RequestMapping(value = "/eventhistory*", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView onSubmit( ExportEventControllerCommandBean cmd, HttpServletResponse response ) throws Exception
    {

    }
}
```

By removing the web.xml stuff, I also no longer have the 'viewResolver' bean in my context. How do I add this again?

Furthermore, my controller gets pickup up by the component scanning, but when I put a breakpoint inside the onSubmit method, it never gets hit. What else do I need to do for migration?

Comment: For the viewResolver you can create an @Configuration class and extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: @MikeR I am not using Java config at the moment. I suppose I can just create the bean in my main application context instead of in the dedicated servlet config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by keeping my `exportServlet-config.xml`. I needed to add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to it.